# How to deal with 404 error questions? (repository/installation related)

Tags: discussion, new-users

As [18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/18.04) is relatively new, not all repositories (including PPAs) are releasing their packages for Bionic. Still, there are constantly questions regarding 404 error while trying to install package(s) from PPAs.

In short, I want to discuss: What to do with questions regarding 404 error on repositories while the original poster wanted to install *that* package? This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) have only answers to remove PPAs.

This can be a future-proofing, so new users can know what to do when they're still want to install a certain package, with knowledge of risk (if there's any) if they want to install the older version for older Ubuntu release.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. To get a technical handle on the situation, are you saying there is a solution other than removing the PPAs that should be used in some situations, or suggesting that when a new version comes out, people should be advised to just wait a little while for the new version, or something else? I think the general advice to just add an answer to the canonical post if you think there is something missing from it applies well here...

Comment: There should be if the OP can't wait for some reason. I experienced that I almost break my system because of *that* way of package installation. Probably, *flagging* that kind of question (as a duplicate) works, but it will take a lot of time to collate data of *which installations are success* and *which aren't*.

Comment: I usually edit the PPA to reflect the latest release it targets, then try to install. It doesn't always work, though.

Comment: That's the point. We need to inform that not all repositories are backward compatible with Bionic.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a generic edit to the existing 404 PPA question or a new one explaining that it's impossible for us to know when a third party will provide packages might be a good catch all?

Comment: That can be a good idea. Probably add another answer to the case if the poster still wanted to proceed installation?

Comment: I tried my best on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039279) .

Comment: @AryoAdhi Well, at least you've got one upvote...